# why am i getting error when trying to open new activity in android studio

Tags: android

[image: error]

I'm getting this error when I write the intent inside the `onCreate` method.
But when I write the intent inside an outer method and call it, it works.

[image: working]

Comment: Fixed the formatting to show the images.

Answer (score 1):

Button click listener is an interface and you implemented it here as an anonymous class, so inside of that class `this` refers to that anonymous class, not your activity class, but `Intent` constructor needs activity class implementation, therefore as @ADITYA RANADE answered you need to change it to `MainActivity.this`.

However if you replace anonymous class with lambda you can avoid this:

```
    Button button = new Button(context);
    button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `MainActivity.this` inside the intent

Comment: why ? what's causing this problem and how does this resolve it ?

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Well that is because of the place or more precisely "context" (not the androidish Context) of where you are calling it.

When you call it from the anonymously created inner class which implements the listener for a view click, so in this case the *this* represents something else - anonymous class.

But on the other side when you make the method e.g. openScheduleActivity() inside the activity itself, the *this* keyword represents the activity itself and in fact represents the androidish **Context** or in this particular case even the activity. So you can either stay with case that you have already had there and slightly edit it, or you can use lambda expression, or you can use the method inside the activity itself as you have already discovered.

edited case:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, schedule.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

lambda expression:

```
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, schedule.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
```